# Проблема с подключением к БД

Tags: база-данных, php

В чём может быть причина и где её исправить?
Это сообщение выскакивает, когда установщик пытается связатся с бд.

> Нет соединения с базой данных.n Access denied for user 'xnova'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

**Добавлено из комментария.**

> `Message: SQL Error: No database selected`
> `Query Code: SELECT HIGH_PRIORITY * FROM`config`WHERE`uni`= '1';`
> `File: /home/xnova/www_html/includes/classes/class.MySQLi.php`
> `Line: 96`
> `URL: http://xnova.gomel.by/index.php`
> `PHP-Version: 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.17`
> `PHP-API: apache2handler`
> `2Moons Version:`
> `Debug Backtrace:`
> `#0 ./includes/classes/class.MySQLi.php(113): DB_mysqli->query('SELECT HIGH_PRI...')`
> `#1 ./includes/GeneralFunctions.php(117): DB_mysqli->uniquequery('SELECT HIGH_PRI...')`
> `#2 ./includes/common.php(90): getConfig(1)`
> `#3 ./index.php(46): require('/home/xnova/www...')`

Answer (score 1):

У пользователя xnova нету прав доступа, если базу данных администрируете сами, то смотреть в сторону настройки прав доступа пользователей базы данных.

Как вариант вы могли добавить пользователя, но разрешить ему соединяться только с определенного хоста.

Попробуйте подключиться к базе данных на пример через phpmyadmin или консоль, чтобы проверить проблемы с доступом или проблемы с установщиком.

Comment: БД не выбрана (mysql_select_db) либо выбрана не та база данных.

Comment: "2moons" как я понял это движок браузерной игры, а "xnova" это пользователь от которого вы пробовали подключиться к базе данных.

Если база данных поддерживается не вами, то скорей всего вы просто не правильно указали в установщике, сервер, имя пользователя или пароль к этой учетной записи.